# Map borders incorrect using matplotlib and xarray

Tags: python, matplotlib, python-xarray

I have an xarray DataArray `da` containing a slice of data for Ireland which looks like this:

```
<xarray.DataArray 'co2' (lat: 733, lon: 720)>
array([[nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan],
   [nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan],
   [nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan],
   ...,
   [nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan],
   [nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan],
   [nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan]])
Coordinates:
  * lat      (lat) float32 49.9 49.908333 49.916664 49.924995 49.933327 ...
  * lon      (lon) float32 -11.0 -10.991667 -10.983334 -10.975 -10.966667 ...
```

I want to make a map of it using the Irish coastline and administrative boundaries. I can do this using matplotlib and basemap, The `DataArray` is a slice of a `DataSet` where the lat and lon coords are used as the boundaries:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import xarray
import os
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap, cm

m= Basemap(projection='cyl',lat_0=ds.co2.lat[0],lon_0=ds.co2.lon[len(ds.co2.lon)/2])
m.drawcoastlines()
da.plot()
```

The problem is that the border on this map is very crude and looks terrible, and is missing the internal administrative boundaries:

[image]

How do I change the parameters so the coastline is more realistic and I can get the internal administrative boundaries?

Comment: Have a look at the [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/basemap/api/basemap_api.html): you can change the resolution in your `Basemap()` call. The default value is 'c' for "crude" and you would get the best possible resolution with 'f' for "full".

Comment: @Thomas, oh, I hadn't realized that - thank you! Now to find out how to draw administrative boundaries...

Comment: @Thomas, you wouldn't happen to have any idea why the lat/lon gridlines aren't plotting? When I use the `m.drawparallels()` command I get the error `ValueError: dimensions () must have the same length as the number of data dimensions, ndim=1`